# vc++ problem in situation export/import global variables in dlls

Tags: visual-c++, dllimport, dllexport

**Precondition**

environment : VC2005

I encountered this problem when discovered circular dependency in my project(two dll references each other), so divide either of one dll to two dll's.

explain with example :

```
typedef struct { <br>
    char myFileName[MAX_PATH];
} MyStructure;
```

Before :

MyHeader.h

```
MyStructure globalStruct;
```

After:

MyCommon.h

```
#ifdef _MYGLOBAL_
#define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

API extern MyStructure globalStruct;
```

MyGlobal.c

```
API MyStructure globalStruct;
```

MySpecific.c

```
API MyStructure globalStruct;
```

failed code after changed: (this code run in specific dll)

```
handle = LoadLibrary(globalStruct.myFileName);
```

I confirmed globalStruct.myFileName values are same(at lease real words).

I can't access the value directly with debugger after changed. so, to see value in debugger, I copyed to temp local char[] variable. And then, I found before value and after value are different in tailing dummy char's.

before:
d:[my path] '0'(char end null) **'0' '0' ...** 
after:
d:[my path] '0'(char end null) **'-3' '-3' '-3' ...**

thank you for your reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self-solved my problem.

This is because dll does not re-compiled after my circular dependency removal work.

So, this problem is not related import/export global variable but dll re-compile issue.

Sorry for my ugly question.